# Can it be done? Delete huge amount of files based on how old they are using Powershell

Tags: powershell, delete-file, get-childitem

On server running on Windows 2012 R2, version

```
PS C:\Users\admin> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

I need to delete files older than 180 days in a folder with a lot of subfolders. That is quite simple, **BUT** not when there are hundreds of thousands of files and the folder is about 800GB. Using Get-ChildItem which first reads all files recursivly while checking the date and then starts deleting them...well, it takes forever and the server did at the end ran out of memory.

So - anyone in the mood to help me speed up my code which currenlty is like this (the delete part)

```
...
...
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -recurse -exclude 
 $skipFilePatterns | where { ! $i.PSIsContainer }) { 

if (! $i.PSIsContainer -and $i.LastWriteTime -lt ($(Get-Date).AddDays(-$keepForDays))) { 
    # Add -WhatIf to test the script, remove it when confirmed
    $timeStamp = $i.LastWriteTime
    $fullName = $i.FullName
    $log.Info("Deleting: $fullName with timestamp (LastWriteTime): $timeStamp")


    Remove-Item $i.FullName -force -ErrorVariable errVar -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
...
...
```

Comment: I would rather slow down the process instead of speed up. Split the work in doable workloads. Use the `-Depth` parameter of  `get-childItem` to get just the first layers of folders and process them `foreach`. Whenever one is done clean up and take the next one.

Comment: On the other hand you can delete whole directories that haven't been accessed for 180 days. Without the need to list every single file in them...

Comment: I guess that the answer is that it can be done, but other languages / tools can or will be faster and more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can use `Select -first $Limit`

Second no need to exclude Folders `$i.PSIsContainer` you can just tell `Get-ChildItem` (alias `GCI`) to only get files using the `-File` param

Something like

```
function Remove-ChildItemsInChunks($keepForDays, $Limit, $Path){
    $count = 0
    gci $Path -Recurse -File | 
        ?{$i.LastWriteTime -lt ($(Get-Date).AddDays(-$keepForDays))} |
        select -First $Limit | %{
            $count += 1
            Remove-Item $_
        }
    return $Count
}


$GCICount = Get-ChildItemsInChunks -Path C:\test -keepForDays 30 -Limit 500
while($GCICount -gt 0){
    $GCICount = Get-ChildItemsInChunks -Path C:\Test -keepForDays 30 -Limit 500
}
```

Comment: I like the idea but note that you traverse many folders over and over again until there's nothing more to delete. On such a large folderstructure, that is going to kill performance.

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers, I agree that traversing the folder multiple times will slow it down, but the main problem is running out-of-memory and terminating the script. And it seems like you won't be traversing empty folders too frequently if chunk sizes are large. It would take some experimentation to find the sweet spot of $Limit for performance. 
Another option is to split the parent paths to chunks, but that's more complicated.

Comment: Limit does not help in my case, but I did remove the $i.PSIsContainer. Ended up instad of spending to much time trying to tune the script to select one subfolder at the time, that made it doable. After having deleted 700GB, the script now perform quite well - so runing it every night will take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using the pipeline all the way through, otherwise you're gathering everything in memory first.  Using regex would probably be more efficient in the `Where-Object` filter rather than using `-Exclude` (which is notoriously inefficient).

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)
$skipFilePatterns = @() # probably some collection of wildcard strings

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Exclude $skipFilePatterns |
    Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt $limit |
    ForEach-Object {
        $timeStamp = $PSItem.LastWriteTime.ToString('o') # ISO-8601-compliant string
        $fullName = $PSItem.FullName
        $log.Info("Deleting: $fullName with timestamp (LastWriteTime): $timeStamp")
        $PSItem
    } | Remove-Item -Force -ErrorVariable errVar -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: To stay in one pipe without ForEach you evtl. could log with ` |Select-Object FullName,LastWriteTime | Tee-Object -FilePath ".\somefile.log" -Append | Remove-Item ...`

Comment: @LotPings `$log` looks like a custom logging object they've created.

Comment: Ack, if speed **IS** an issue a pure text log might be the minor problem. Easy for me as my datetime output is nearly ISO8601.

Comment: @LotPings There's also inherent slowness interacting with a disk drive and file system abstraction that you cannot work around.  It might make more sense to use a purpose-built utility like robocopy for what they're trying to do, but I'm completely out of my element with that application.  I was more trying to assist with their "out of memory" issue which is being caused by trying to load all the file objects into memory first.

Comment: I guess that this answer could also be marked as "accepted", but I did not spend to much time rewriting the script - but thanks anyhow!